# table.innerHTML = ""; doesn't properly clear HTML table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I'm creating a table with JavaScript after selecting a key e.g., `European Countries` and value e.g., `Population` which calls an API and then returns to the front end, outputting a table:

```
Countries:   Population:

France                67
Germany               83
UK                    66
```

When I select a new value e.g., `GDP`, it clears the table fine and re-renders it again properly, like so:

```
Countries:           GDP:

France                2.7
Germany               3.8
UK                    2.8
```

However if I select a new key `Asian Countries`, a new table gets appended to the existing one:

```
Countries:           GDP:

France                2.7
Germany               3.8
UK                    2.8
China                14.3
Japan                 5.0
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
1  renderTable() {
2      var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
3      tbody.innerHTML = "";
4      var obj = this.state;
5      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
6          var tr = "<tr>";
7          tr += `<td>${key}</td><td>${value.toString()}</td></tr>`;
8          tbody.innerHTML += tr;
9      }
10  }
```

and the HTML before the table has been rendered:

```
1 <table>
2     <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
3 <table>
```

So currently, the table gets removed and a new one created when a new **value** is selected, but a new table is simply appended when a new **key** is selected. How can I make sure the table gets cleared and then re-rendered each time, regardless if I'm selecting a new key or value?

EDIT:

`this.state` is an object with country names as keys - it looks like the following:

```
France: 67
Germany: 83
UK: 66
...
```

The "selections" come from two `Form.Groups`s:

```
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Label>Continent</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="select" multiple id="select-continent"> 
         <option value="asia">Asia</option>
         <option value="europe">Europe</option>
    </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>

<Form.Group>
    <Form.Label>Attribute</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="select" multiple id="select-attribute"> 
         <option value="Population">Country Population (millions)</option>
         <option value="GDP">GDP (USD) </option>
    </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>

<Button variant="success" onClick={() => this.callAPI(document.getElementById('select-continent').value, document.getElementById('select-attribute').value)}>
    Search
</Button>
```

with `callAPI()` as the following and `componentDidUpdate` detecting the change in `this.state`:

```
callAPI( continent, attribute ) {
    var h = new Headers();
    h.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    h.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    var raw = JSON.stringify({"continent":continent, "attribute":attribute});

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: h,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch('/api/continents-countries', requestOptions).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
        this.setState(data)
    });
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.state !== this.state) {
        this.renderTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share `this.state`.

Comment: Where do these “selections” you are talking about happen? Pretty much all we know so far, is that you have a function `renderTable`, but no information whatsoever about how where when by what it gets called. Please get into the habit of providing _proper_ [mre]s with questions like this.

Comment: @CBroe please see edits

Comment: `tbody.innerHTML = "";` looks completely fine, so it's probably something elsewhere. Does `var obj = this.state` load the correct data ? If you `console.log(obj)` is it showing what you want ?

Comment: @LSE so after some ```console.log```-ing, you're right, it seems ```this.state``` is having the newly selected data appended

Comment: Also, please try and _tag_ your questions appropriately. The form code you have shown is not actually HTML, and the scripting is not “plain” JS either, but looks more like this was React or something.

Comment: @mlan I'm not particularly skilled with what it looks like React, but if you're resetting everything, can't you just reset the `state` too ? Inside that `fetch`, before `setState`, you could empty the `state` before setting it.

Comment: @LSE yes, currently looking at how I can properly reset/empty ```this.state```. Thanks!

Comment: @CBroe done so, thanks. I mistakenly thought it was simply a plain JS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[index]` of the `<tbody>` element instead of the id.

```js
function renderTable() {
      var tbody = document.getElementById("myTable").tBodies[0];
      tbody.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<style>table, td {border: 1px solid black;}</style>

<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p><button onclick="renderTable()">Erase tbody</button>
```